# How to extract lines that come in between two headers starting with a specific character?

Tags: scala

I am trying to read a file from local in scala as below.

```
val inpFile = "/Users/Abcde/Downloads/data.txt"
def loadFromLocal:Unit = {
    val lines = Source.fromFile(inpFile).getLines.toList
    println("Lines: " + lines.size)
}
```

The data inside the file is present as below:

```
#HRec300 1940 10 18 99 2200    7          bnk-dep
31 -9999  -9999    40 -9999 -9999 -9999    23    20 
30 -9999  -9999   500 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    20 
30 -9999  -9999   750 -9999 -9999 -9999   113    20 
30 -9999  -9999  1000 -9999 -9999 -9999   113    20 
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999   203    10 
30 -9999  -9999  2000 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    20 
30 -9999  -9999  2500 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    30 
#HRec300 1940 10 19 99 1000    6          bnk-dep  
31 -9999  -9999    40 -9999 -9999 -9999     0    30 
30 -9999  -9999   500 -9999 -9999 -9999     0    80 
30 -9999  -9999   750 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    90 
30 -9999  -9999  1000 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    60 
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    40 
30 -9999  -9999  2000 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    40 
#HRec300 1940 10 19 99 2200    6          bnk-dep  
31 -9999  -9999    40 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    70 
30 -9999  -9999   500 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    90 
30 -9999  -9999   750 -9999 -9999 -9999     0   100 
30 -9999  -9999  1000 -9999 -9999 -9999   338   110 
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999   338   110 
30 -9999  -9999  2000 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    80
```

The misc-data is separated by headers i.e. for each header, there are multiple misc-data and each header record starts with first character '#'
I need to pick up the header record for each block and add their corresponding header to the misc-data as below.

```
#HRec300 1940 10 18 99 2200    7          bnk-dep
31 -9999  -9999    40 -9999 -9999 -9999    23    20 HRec300
30 -9999  -9999   500 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    20 HRec300
30 -9999  -9999   750 -9999 -9999 -9999   113    20 HRec300
30 -9999  -9999  1000 -9999 -9999 -9999   113    20 HRec300
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999   203    10 HRec300
30 -9999  -9999  2000 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    20 HRec300
30 -9999  -9999  2500 -9999 -9999 -9999    90    30 HRec300
#HRec301 1940 10 19 99 1000    6          bnk-dep  
31 -9999  -9999    40 -9999 -9999 -9999     0    30 HRec301
30 -9999  -9999   500 -9999 -9999 -9999     0    80 HRec301
30 -9999  -9999   750 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    90 HRec301
30 -9999  -9999  1000 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    60 HRec301
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    40 HRec301
30 -9999  -9999  2000 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    40 HRec301
#HRec302 1940 10 19 99 2200    6          bnk-dep  
31 -9999  -9999    40 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    70 HRec302
30 -9999  -9999   500 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    90 HRec302
30 -9999  -9999   750 -9999 -9999 -9999     0   100 HRec302
30 -9999  -9999  1000 -9999 -9999 -9999   338   110 HRec302
30 -9999  -9999  1500 -9999 -9999 -9999   338   110 HRec302
30 -9999  -9999  2000 -9999 -9999 -9999   338    80 HRec302
```

Could anyone let me know how can I fetch blocks of data between two header records in a file ?

Comment: you can concat the data and then split it by #

Comment: How do you want to collect the data? In separate objects ?, in dataframes? files ?

Comment: I am trying to save the data in a collection and do a batch insert into another table excluding the header records. I have written the logic to exclude the headers but unable to write the other one I mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function that creates *Records*

Here the simplest version:

```
  case class Record(title: String, lines: List[String] = Nil)

  @tailrec
  def createRecords(lines: List[String], records: List[Record]): List[Record] =
    lines match {
      case Nil => records // no work to do anymore
      case x::xs if x.startsWith("#") => createRecords(xs, Record(x)::records) // a new Record
      case x::xs =>
        val rec = records.head
        createRecords(xs, rec.copy(lines = x::rec.lines)::records.tail) // include line to existing Record
    }
```

Usage: `createRecords(lines, Nil)`, check [scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/dA3ZK22/1)

- `lines` are from your example (`val lines = Source.fromFile(inpFile).getLines.toList`)
- `records` accumulates the solution (so it is tail recursive and does not blow up the stack)

Be aware:

- there is no exception handling (if the data is not as nice)
- the order of the Records and its lines are reverse.

Comment: Can you explain the two parameters: lines: List[String], records: List[Record] inside createRecords Method ? What do they correspond to ?

Comment: I added the explanation to my answer - check alse the comments I added on each line in the recursive function.